# Number of Planted Plane Trees, Every Node Multiple of m

Tags: graph-theory, generating-functions, trees

I am looking to find the number of planted plane trees (PPT) on $mn+1$ nodes, such that the number of upward branches on each node is a multiple of $m$, for integer $m$ $\ge$ 2.

---

Here is what I have so far:
Let $P(x)$ be the generating function with $x$ being all nodes. Then the following $P(x)$ enumerates the number of PPT on $n$ nodes, for which the number of upward branches on each node is exactly equal to $m$.
\begin{align} P(x) & = x(m+mP+mP^2+mP^3+...) \\\\ & = x \cdot m(1+P+P^2+P^3+...) \\\\ & = x \cdot m(1-P)^{-1} \end{align}
Then to find the exact number of PPT on this many nodes, we would have to extract the coefficient $[x^nt^m]$, by using the Lagrange Inversion Formula where $\phi(t) = (1-t)^{-1}$.

However, I am looking for the number of branches on each node to be a *multiple* of m, not necessarily m itself (or am I correct in my original interpretation?).  Also, I am looking for the total number of nodes to be $mn+1$, not $n$.

Any thoughts on how I can rework the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is asking about the combinatorial class
$\mathcal{T}$ where

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}
+ \mathcal{Z} \times
\textsc{SEQ}_{=m, =2m, =3m, \ldots}(\mathcal{T}).$$

These are rooted plane trees with outdegree a multiple of $m.$ This
yields the functional equation

$$T(z) = z + z \times ( T(z)^m + T(z)^{2m} + T(z)^{3m} + \cdots)
\\ = z \times (1 + T(z)^m + T(z)^{2m} + T(z)^{3m} + \cdots)
\\ = z \frac{1}{1-T(z)^m}$$

which also produces

$$z = (1-T(z)^m) T(z).$$

To extract coefficients on this consult the entry for the [Lagrange
Inversion Formula at
Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)  and
take $\phi(w)=1/(1-w^m)$ to obtain for $q$ nodes

$$\frac{1}{q} [w^{q-1}] \frac{1}{(1-w^m)^q}.$$

Here we see that $q-1$ must be a multiple of $m$ so we put $q=mn+1$ to
get

$$\frac{1}{mn+1} [w^{mn}] \frac{1}{(1-w^m)^{mn+1}}
= \frac{1}{mn+1} [w^n] \frac{1}{(1-w)^{mn+1}}.$$

We have the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{mn+1} {mn+n\choose n}.}$$